# checkbox always in unchecked status no matter if is checked or not

Tags: checkbox, unchecked

I am using chekbox in my code but its always showing unchecked .I am using the chekbox as show below in my form and on submit ion i am cheking the value with if statement as shown below

```
    <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="auto"><p>I accept </p>
    </label>


if(isset($_POST['auto']))
{
    echo "checked";
 }
 else
{
   echo "unchecked";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some browser do not support defalut value of "on". This is a more stable solution -

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="auto" value="on" /><p>I accept </p>
</label>
```

And then the same php code.

```
if(isset($_POST['auto'])) {
    echo "checked";
} else {
    echo "unchecked";
}
```